# vertical integral projection to separate every teeth

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to separate every single teeth in radiograph image. First, at upper jaw, I want to separate every single teeth.

I have the image of upper jaw. And then I make it into binary(thresholding) image, and I make the plot of the image matrix(m n) which I make the mean of the colomns  : this the plot coding :

```
[m1, n1]=size(maxila); %maxila is the name of upper jaw image
Po1=0:1:n1-1;
Vmean1=mean(maxila,1);
Figure
plot(Po1,vmean1);
```

Okay, after that the plot show up, and I want to get the every mean point which mean go to zero(0) and plot it, and that will be the plot to separate the teeth.. Some help please...
Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
sep = find( mean( maxila, 1 ) == 0 ); % gives you the column indices of seperations
```

Comment: It doesn't work...hmm 
I want to make the plot every teeth that will be more than one vertical line

Comment: I think may be use iteration?? After do first line of separate then continue the next separate line, any suggestions please?